# VARCHAR comparison on an indexed column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Postgres is behaving differently from the 'common sense' expected behavior:

Given a table 'my_table' and a VARCHAR(250) column named 'MyVarcharColumn' where an index IDX_MyvarcharColumn is created based on the 'MyVarcharColumn'.

```
Collation: Default
Postgres version: 11.12
LC_COLLATE: en_US.utf8
Enconding: UTF8
CTYPE: en_US.utf8
```

The problem is presented below:

Given a query (A)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t
WHERE 'mystring' = t.MyVarcharColumn
```

When running the query above, no records are returned even though there is a value 'mystring' present in 'my_table'.

Workaround:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t
WHERE 'mystring' = t.MyVarcharColumn collate "C"
```

By adding 'collate "C"' the query works fine, obviously no one wants to have to add the "collate" statement at the end of every query.

Second 'Workaround':

By recreating the databases indexes 'REINDEX database myDB' the query also starts to work as expected without the need of adding the statement 'collate'.

The question is: is there a way to avoid using the collate statement and/or the REINDEX to make this work without a workaround?

- Re-creating the database with a different collation it also not an option at the moment.
- Using lower(column_name) to compare isn't an option since it does not use indexes and it would make the query slow.

Comment: Are you using Linux and did you recently get an operating system update? Then you are probably affected by the [Locale data changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) in Linux

Comment: What  does `show lc_collate ;` return? Add as update to your question.